# Regex that will exclude a capture group

Tags: regex

I'm writing a regex that I need to catch strings that are plurial starting with "get". For instance `getContacts` and `getBuildings` should match the regex.  However there are times where the text may equal getDetails or `get**Details`. I do not want the regex to include these.

I can come up with a regex that includes the matching group "Details", but I want to exclude that capture group, not include it.

```
[Gg]et?\w+([Dd]etail)s
```

I'm not very strong at regex but heres my understanding of what I wrote:

match "g" or "G" followed by "et" then optionally any word character, then the matching group, followed by "s".

How can I exclude results that have the word "details"?

Comment: Should `getDetailsAndBars` match or not?

Comment: should `getInfo` match? your original regex appears to exclude that case.

Comment: Why do you have the question mark in `[Gg]et?`? The `?` just makes the `t` optional. Was that your intention?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this could work for you:

```
\b[Gg]et(?!\w*[Dd]etails)\w+s\b
```

Comment: The negative lookahead `(?!...)` makes sure that Details is not part of that match, `\b`s are used to anchor the match at the beginning/end of words, otherwise `GetBars` would match in this sting `setGetBarsX`.

Answer (score 10):

I believe you are looking for zero-width negative lookahead...

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

```
[Gg]et(?![Dd]etail)\w+s
```

Assuming you want to exclude "Get Details", and "Get Info" but accept "Get Pages" and "Get MyDetails" (N.B. the trailing s in your original regex excludes "Get Info" already)

Comment: You may want a trailing `\b` or `$` on there, so that you don't match `getSass` in `getSassDetails`.

Comment: Awesome! Thats closer.  But it looks like its still matching strings with details: http://regexr.com?301ut  can you tell me how to exclude those strings?

Comment: -1, `?` after the `t` is wrong, and op seems to indicate that `Details` doesn't have to be adjacent to `get`.

Comment: @Qtax oops, yes copied that from his original, was thinking about the negative match aspect and didn't notice that.

Comment: actually the negative look behind covers the cases you put in regexr, but not getSomeDetailsAndNotOthers... so if you need to exclude that too then use Qtax's solution. I was only trying to exclude things ending in "details"...