# Is there a regex that will match a string that contains a non fixed width string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here are two example strings:

> 'If <Person>, is for any reason unwilling or unable to serve, <next.Person > shall instead serve as successor agent.'

> 'If <Person>, is for any reason unwilling or unable to serve, <next.Person> shall instead serve as successor agent.'

I'm looking to match the second, and *not* the first, there can be no whitespaces inside the `<>`'s. I've tried several [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332878/regex-that-will-exclude-a-capture-group), negative lookbehind will not work because the chars inside the `<>` are not fixed width.

I'm looking for a pattern that would match everything inside the `''`'s  when none of the `<>` sections contain a space (`\s` to be regex-specific). As shown in the example above there can be multiple `<>`'s inside the string, and the string can contain pretty much any valid characters outside of the pattern I wish to exclude.

Comment: It's trivial if you're willing to go slightly beyond using a single `RegExp`...

Comment: I see your string is delimited with single-quotes - but what should happen if an input string contains apostrophes that _don't_ terminate the string?

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing the difference between the two strings.

Comment: @Dai Not sure I can go beyond a single regex, but it could provide the path to an alternative. Double quotes could be used to wrap the string if it contained apostrophes as an alternative.

Comment: @Barmar there is a space inside `<next.Person >` in the first string, but not the second.

Comment: Instead of using a regexp to match the 2nd, use it to match the 1st and then exclude it.

Comment: @Barmar I need to match `'....'` when `'....'` does not include `<space inside>`

Comment: Perhaps a negative lookahead for a space inside `<>`? [`^(?!.*<[^>]*\s[^>]*>).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/pUraOX/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:<[^\s<>]*>|[^<>])*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K3ayqd/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:<[^\s<>]*>|[^<>])*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `<[^\s<>]*>` - a `<`, zero or more chars other than `<`, `>` and whitespace and then a `>` char
  - `|` - or
  - `[^<>]` - a char other than `<` and `>`
- `$` - end of string.